# Add action to fire when a published post is updated

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, actions

I have a couple of actions setup:

```
add_action('publish_post', array($this, 'newPost'), 10, 2); 
add_action('post_updated', array($this, 'updatePost'), 10, 3);
```

When I update an already published post the 'newPost' method is fired as opposed to the 'updatePost' method.  I imagine this is because the post is already published so what would be a good way to fire a different method (or be able to identify that it's an update as opposed to a newly published post) when a previously published post is updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, you can make use of the 'transition_post_status' hook for this. This hook is fired whenever a post's status is changed. In your case, you need to check whether the old and new status of the post is the same, which is `publish`

You can also set conditionals according to `$post`, which is the current post being updated/published etc.

You can try the following:

```
add_action('transition_post_status', function ($new_status, $old_status, $post) {

   if ( $old_status == 'publish' && $new_status == 'publish' ) {
       //Do something when post is updated
   }

}, 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [post status transition](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) actions for this.

```
function wpd_updating_a_published_post( $post ){
    // do something
}
add_action( 'publish_to_publish', 'wpd_updating_a_published_post', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Milo: This seems like a very concise way to do it.  The only problem is that my 'publish_page' and 'publish_post' actions get fired as well.  How can I check in those methods if the page/post is an existing one?

Comment: Never mind, I got it!

Answer (score 1):

You can user Milo 's answer or you can use the conditional inside the hooked function, and then compare the `post_date` and the `post_modified`.

```
add_action('save_post', array($this, 'updatePost'), 10, 3);

function updatePost($post_id){

// If this is just a revision, don't send the email.
if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
    return;

$post = get_post($post_id);

// Compare the date
if ($post->post_date == $post->post_modified){
    // Do something for a new post

} elseif ($post->post_date < $post->post_modified){
    // Do something for an updated post
}
```